# Can you store an 'It' matcher object as a variable, instead of defining it inline? (Moq)

Tags: c#, .net, mocking, moq

I'm mocking some objects using Moq, and some of them can have fairly lengthy parameter-collection request objects passed in as arguments.

For ease of re-use and style, I'd like to be able to store these requests, with specific arguments, for use in the mocking setup. For example:

```
mockedObject
  .Setup(mo =>
    mo.GetBobbins(It.Is<GetBobbinsRequest>
      (r.Parameter1 == value1 && [...] & r.ParameterN == valueN))
  .Returns(someBobbins);
```

becomes:

```
var request = It.Is<GetBobbinsRequest>
  (r.Parameter1 == value1 && [...] & r.ParameterN == valueN);
mockedObject
  .Setup(mo => mo.GetBobbins(request))
  .Returns(someBobbins);
```

But that doesn't seem to work. I also tried:

```
Func<GetBobbinsRequest> request = () => It.Is<GetBobbinsRequest>
  (r.Parameter1 == value1 && [...] & r.ParameterN == valueN);
mockedObject
  .Setup(mo => mo.GetBobbins(request()))
  .Returns(someBobbins);
```

But no joy there either. Is there any way I can save an `It`style object as a variable? Or am I missing some other obvious way of handling this?

Answer (score 7):

And... I've found the answer. It's Moq's Match (Class):

> Creating a custom matcher is straightforward. You just need to create
>   a method that returns a value from a call to Create with your
>   matching condition and optional friendly render expression:

```
[Matcher]
public Order IsBigOrder()
{
    return Match<Order>.Create(
        o => o.GrandTotal >= 5000, 
        /* a friendly expression to render on failures */
        () => IsBigOrder());
}
```

> This method can be used in any mock setup invocation:

```
mock.Setup(m => m.Submit(IsBigOrder()).Throws<UnauthorizedAccessException>();
```

http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/Moq/Moq/Match(T)

Answer (score 7):

A quick explanation as to why what you have in your question doesn't work, since I wrote it up before seeing your answer:

The call to `It.Is` actually ends up [returning `default(T)` every time](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/blob/master/Source/It.cs#L72), so storing it and using it later would be the same as just passing `null` or whatever the default value of the parameter type is.

The reason why it has to be inline is because the call to `It.Is` actually works by [setting a static member in a "mock context"](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/blob/master/Source/Match.cs#L68) that the call to `Setup` [eventually](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/blob/master/Source/Mock.cs#L432) [gets](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/blob/master/Source/MethodCall.cs#L148) [around](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/blob/master/Source/MatcherFactory.cs#L90) to using.